# Float arithemtic and double precision?

Tags: java, floating-point, language-agnostic

I was confused by the difference between `float` and `double`. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/4671213). I thought the the difference is just in precision. So I expected that if `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` returns `false` then either does `0.1f + 0.2f == 0.3f`.

But actually `0.1f + 0.2f == 0.3f` returns `true`. Why that?

Is that a pure Java issue or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's just an artifact of the decimal-binary conversion.

Under the hood, floating point numbers are represented in binary. The number 0.1 can't be represented exactly in binary, so it needs to be rounded to the nearest representable number, of which the `float` is:

0.100000001490116119384765625

and the `double` is:

0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625

So it turns out that if you add the `double` nearest 0.1, and the `double` nearest 0.2, then round that result to the nearest `double`, you don't actually get the `double` nearest 0.3, but instead you get the one after it (which is typically printed as `0.30000000000000004`, but actually has a lot more digits), hence the lack of equality.

On the other hand, if you add the `float` nearest 0.1, and the `float` nearest 0.2, then round that result to the nearest `float`, you *do* get the `float` nearest 0.3, hence the equality.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't ever compare floats or doubles for equality, you can't really guarantee that the number you assign to the float or double is exact

Comment: This statement is *way* too strong. There are plenty of situations where it's entirely reasonable to compare floats or doubles for equality.